Combinatorics: Distribute 12 elements into 1 to 4 heaps
I have the following problem:
How many ways are there to distribute the numbers 1,2,...,12 into 1 to 4 heaps?
So for example:

All numbers on one heap.
The numbers 1,...,6 onto one heap and 7,...,12 onto the other (1,...6 / 7,...,12)
1,3,5 into one heap, 2,4,6 on the second heap, 7 and 8 on one heap and 9,10,11,12 on the forth heap (1,3,5 / 2,4,6 / 7,8 / 9,10,11,12).

My first idea was $4^{12}$ because each number can be in one of the four heaps. But you cannot distinguish between the heaps, therefore 1,...,6 / 7,...,12 and  7,...,12 / 1,...,6 should be the same solution.
I think the solution is the sum of the Stirling numbers of the second kind, hence $S(12,1)$ up to $S(12,5)$ or $\sum_{i=1}^5 S(12,i)$. Is this correct?

When you divide into heaps, are the heaps to have equal numbers, or all possivle distributions ?

The heaps do not need to have equal numbers.
So 3,5,7 / 1,2,4,12 / 6,8,9 / 10,11 is possible.

Yes, if you distribute 12 (distinguishable) numbers into k indistinguishable non-empty sets (I assume the ordering within each heap is irrelevant/fixed), then the number of possibilities in the Stirling number of the second kind $S(12, k)$, which you can sum for k from 1 to 4, and I don't think this can be much simplified in any way.
As you say, $4^{12}$ would overcount solutions which only differ in how heaps are permuted. In fact, $4^{12}$ counts ways to distribute into four labeled possibly-empty heaps. So each solution to your problem with would be counted as many times as there are labelings of the non-empty heaps into $\{1,2,3,4\}$. For a solution with $k$ non-empty heaps that number is $\binom{4}{k} k!$ (also denoted as the falling factorial $(4)_k$ sometimes), hence $4^{12} = \sum_{k=0}^4 S(12,k) \binom{4}{k} k!$
Actually using the fact that $x^{12} = \sum_{k=0}^{12} S(12,k) \binom{x}{k} k!$ in general (where the summands are zero for $k > x$ assuming integer $x$), for $x=1,2,3,4$, you get a system of linear equalities from which you can compute $S(12,k)$ or their sum perhaps a bit faster than from other formulas for Stirling numbers:
$$
4^{12} = 24 {12 \brace 4} + 24 {12 \brace 3} + 12 {12 \brace 2} + 4 {12 \brace 1}\\
3^{12} = 6 {12 \brace 3} + 6 {12 \brace 2} + 3{12 \brace 1}\\
2^{12} = 2 {12 \brace 2} + 2{12 \brace 1}\\
1^{12} = {12 \brace 1}
$$

I thought you were trying to compute for some possible divisions into heaps. Of course, if you want to sum up all possible divisions into identical non-empty heaps, you would use Stirling numbers of the second kind, so $\sum_{i=1}^4 S(12,i)$

If someone wants to know how to compute for some possible division into heaps, the proces is as under
Basically it is like dividing into teams.
The important thing to remember that basically, if heaps are all of the same size, they will be treated as unlabeled, but if they are of different sizes, they are labeled, and if some are of equal size, that part will be treated as unlabeled.
It will all be clear by one example of dividing into $4$ heaps
$3-3-3-3:\; \binom{12}3\binom93\binom63\binom33\color{red}{\div 4}$ because four unlabeled heaps
$5-4-2-1:\;\binom{12}5\binom74\binom32\binom11\;$
No division needed as different sizes make the heaps labeled
$4-4-3-1:\;\binom{12}4\binom84\binom43\binom11\color{red}{\div2}$
Division by $2$ because $2$ of the heaps become unlabeled due to same size

Thanks for the answer. That would be a lot of work.
Meanwhile I've found the notion of Stirling number of the second kind. Could I simply add up S(12,1) to S(12,5)?

@garondal: No, Stirling numbers would apply only if the heaps were indistinguishable
